# How can I code a program that will encode a text written only in capital letters according to the text below?

Tags: c

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6  
1 A B C D E F
2 G H I J K L
3 M N O P R S
4 T U V Y Z W
5 X 1 2 3 4 5
6 6 7 8 9 ? !
7 - + *
```

I want to do that.

HELLO 1234 equivalent -> 221526263352535455

It is output that I got.

636465

I started with a simple logic, but could not continue.

My codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,j;
    
  
    char string[20];
  char b[7][6]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U'
  ,'V','Y','Z','W','X','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','?','!','-','+','*'};
  printf("please enter an input");
  scanf("%s",&string);
  
  
  for(i=0;i<7;i++){
    for(j=0;j<6;j++){
        if(string[i]==b[i][j])
            printf("%d%d",i,j);
            
      }
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need of `&` in `scanf`.

Comment: I've made a correction but still can't get the output I want.

Comment: it would be easier if you change the `b[][]` to be indexed by letters, like `b['H'] = 22` ...

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: How do I create a for loop afterwards? What should the value ranges be?

Comment: What is your goal of the `for`-loop? You want to go trough the table and the string with the same counter variable, which makes no sense.

Comment: Replace `'L'` with `'Q'` then the alphabet will be "No-el" 

Comment: Yes, but how else can I print the numbers in the table side by side? For example, how can I print the row value of matrix 1 and column value 5 for the letter 'E'?

Comment: You need to iterate over `string[k]`. Use a debugger.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)....) You'll need a good editor such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Enable all warnings and debug info, so compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You could take inspiration from the source code of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and you could use [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over `string` characters and check if the current char is found in `b`.
If it's found you can just print the `row+1` and the `column+1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char b[7][6]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U'
  ,'V','Y','Z','W','X','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','?','!','-','+','*'};

void findRowCol(char c,int *row,int *col){// change row,col to the founded index, if not found to -1
     *row=-1;
     *col=-1;
     for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            if(c==b[i][j]){
              *row=i;
              *col=j;
          }
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char string[20] = "HELLO1234";

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){
       int row,col;
       findRowCol(string[i],&row,&col);
       if(row!=-1) printf("%d%d",row+1,col+1);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created an char array of 256 elements, to account for all ASCII characters. I stored corresponding value of the character in the array.
For example: A-->11,  `alpha_num['A'] = 11`. Similarily, I assigned all the remaining characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    int k = 0;
    char alpha_num[256];
    char string[20];
    printf("Please enter an input\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
    {
        if (j <= 6 && i <= 7)
        {
            alpha_num[c] = i * 10 + j;
            j++;
        }
        if (j > 6)
        {
            j = 1;
            i++;
        }

        if (i > 7)
            i = 1;
    }

    i = 5;
    j = 2;
    for (char c = '1'; c <= '9'; c++)
    {
        if (j <= 6 && i <= 7)
        {
            alpha_num[c] = i * 10 + j;
            j++;
        }
        if (j > 6)
        {
            j = 1;
            i++;
        }

        if (i > 7)
            i = 1;
    }

    alpha_num['?'] = 65;
    alpha_num['!'] = 66;
    alpha_num['-'] = 71;
    alpha_num['+'] = 72;
    alpha_num['*'] = 73;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        printf("%d", alpha_num[string[i]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Please enter an input
HELLO1234
221526263352535455
```

Answer (score 1):

I went for short and simple:

#### ([IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/kJXbtL))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encode(char* input, char* output, char* matrix)
{
    while(*input)
    {
        size_t idx = strchr(matrix, *input++) - matrix;
        *output++ = '1' + idx / 6;
        *output++ = '1' + idx % 6;
    }
    *output = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char matrix[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVYZWX123456789?!-+* ";
    char input[50];
    
    printf("please enter an input");
    fgets(input, 50, stdin);
    *strchr(input, '\n') = '\0';
    
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    char output[2*len +1];
    
    encode(input, output, matrix);
    printf("\nEncoded String: %s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

struct CodeList {
   int code;   
   int key;
};

int main()
{
   struct CodeList  list[6*7];
   int i = 1;
   int y =1;
   int x =1;

   for (char c = 'A'; c <='Z'; c++){
        if (x  > 6) {
           x =1;
           y++;

       }

        if (y  > 7) {
           y =1;
       }
       list[i].key = c;  
       list[i].code = (y * 10) + x;
       i++;
       x++;
  
   }
   
   //search
   char s = 'D';
   
   for (i =0; i< 6*7; i++){
       if(s == list[i].key){
         printf("code %i", list[i].code);// 14

       }
   }
}
```

**By the way, you ignored the letter Q.**